# Expected number of connected components in a proximity graph on random points

Tags: probability, geometry, graph-theory, expected-value, random-graphs

Suppose we select $n$ random points within a circle (independent, with [continuous uniform distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_uniform_distribution)). Then we connect each point to its closest neighbor with an edge (note that "being the closest neighbor" is not necessarily a symmetric relation, i.e. the closest neighbor of the closest neighbor of a point $A$ is not necessarily the point $A$). The result is a graph that may have several [connected components](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_component_(graph_theory)). Let's call the number of points in a connected component its *size*.

- What is the [expected number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value) of connected components in that graph?
  What is the asymptotic behavior of that number when $n\to\infty\,?$
- What is the expected [median](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median) size of those connected components?
  What is the asymptotic behavior of that size when $n\to\infty\,?$
- What are the answers if instead of a circle (2-dimensional) we select random points within a sphere (3-dimensional)?

[image: proximity graph on random points in a circle]

Comment: For square, the expected number of connected components is around $0.31n$, see [this](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/47034/number-of-connected-components-of-a-random-nearest-neighbor-graph) on cstheory.SE. I will suspect for circle, the number also scale with $n$ with a coefficient not that different from that of square.

Comment: Thanks! My intuition tells me that for large $n$, the exact shape of the area should not be important. So, in the asymptotic formula, I would expect the constant in the linear term to be the same regardless of whether it is a circle or a square.